# xlrd error: Workbook file is encrypted

Tags: python, xlrd

Python says xls file is encrypted but I can open it on windows.
What is the problem?

`from xlrd import *
from xlwt import *
f = open_workbook('test.xls')`

Comment: Does this workbook contain any protected sheets? If so, see the comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789951/xlrd-error-workbook-is-encrypted-python-3-2-3

Comment: there is just one comment

Comment: Yes. And that comment says that if a sheet is marked as protected then internally Excel will encrypt the workbook with the fixed password "VelvetSweatshop". Unfortunately, `xlrd` can't handle password-protected files.

Comment: But you may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450773/4014959 . It doesn't let you load the workbook directly into your Python script, but it does show how you can use Python to get Excel to create an unencrypted version of the workbook.

Comment: I had the same problem. I saved the doc as an .xlsx file, it notified me it would be "macro free". Then I could open it no probs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the com.client instead of the xlrd module which can not handle the encrypted excel, just like this

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.open('test.xls')
sheet = workbook.WorkSheets('sheet name')
## get the cell value
row,col = 1,1
sheet.Cells(row,col).value
```